# How do I make rounded corners on app screen?

Tags: iphone, screen

As some of you may have noticed, most (if not all) of system apps show the screen with rounded corners. I mean, the four corners of the device screen look rounded.

However, most of third party apps don't (the corners are 90º), but I've seen some that do, as Facebook messenger. Many others have this effect but only on the splash screen (which may be only a modification to the default.png image file)

Is there a property to achieve this effect?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you want the rounded corners over the ENTIRE app, and not have to explicitly recreate them with every different View Controller you want, call it in AppDelegate: (didFinishLaunching method)

```
[self.window.layer setCornerRadius:20.0];
[self.window.layer setMasksToBounds:YES];
self.window.layer.opaque = NO;
```

Don't forget to:

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
```

This way is better because it creates the animation on the WINDOW, and not the VIEW. So you can design the rest of the UI with 90˚ corners, and they'll automatically be rounded. It's much easier calling it once.

It also may be better for performance to rasterize the layer, especially if it lags:

```
[self.window.layer setShouldRasterize:YES];
[self.window.layer setRasterizationScale:[UIScreen mainScreen].scale];
```

The above will force the animation/graphic change to "act like an image" without making the UI too heavy. Performance will improve, and rasterize according to Retina or Non-Retina Screens. (This is the [UIScreen] call, as ".scale" returns 2.0 for retina, and 1.0 for non-retina. Very, very simple.

Hope this helped! Tick if so and I'll come back and see! :)

Comment: Well thanks for the explanation, however the performance was greatly affected both using it on window or specific views. I'd better not use it but it's good to know how to do it.

Comment: No problem :). Though Rasterising the effect should've eliminated the lag :/

Comment: Works great, except for the top corners are not rounded... maybe because of the status bar?

Comment: For me it lags LESS without resterizing! :O iOS 6 used, tested with iPhone 4.

Comment: Strange. I know if you're doing this on a UIImage or any sort of View you need to Rasterize it for performance reasons. Especially if they're static images (i.e. you don't interact with it by programatically changing it/adding subviews).

Comment: It might seem obvious, but for this to work correctly over an entire app, all `UIWindow` instances should be configured this way. I've been using `UIWindow` instances to show custom-drawn alerts and these new windows are completely separated from the main `UIWindow` (four years late comment, but still... it might be useful for someone else).

Comment: @AlejandroIván, glad you found it useful! Btw instead of using multiple UIWindow you could grab a reference to the AppDelegate one ;)

Answer (score 1):

Following will round the corners of a view.  You can put it in viewDidLoad:

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

view.layer.cornerRadius = 7;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
// Import QuartzCore.h at the top of the file
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>


self.view.layer.backgroundColor = [UIColor orangeColor].CGColor;
self.view.layer.cornerRadius = 20.0;
self.view.layer.frame = CGRectInset(self.view.layer.frame, 20, 20);
```

Check out the [Introduction to CALayers Tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/2502/introduction-to-calayers-tutorial). You will get good start up.

Comment: Do you know how to change just the top (or bottom) corners (like a UITableViewCell in a grouped format)?

Comment: @Inafziger : Make the view clear-color and put rounded corner image.

Answer (score 0):

@PsycoDad: This addition to @cocotouch's answer fixed the top part of the screen

```
CGFloat statusBarHeight = [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarFrame.size.height;
CGRect screenBounds = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
self.window.layer.frame = self.window.layer.bounds = 
  CGRectMake(0, 
             statusBarHeight,
             screenBounds.size.width,
             screenBounds.size.height - statusBarHeight);
```